# vs 2010 connect to oracle with odp.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, odp.net

I have a simple form in Visual Studio 2010 that connects to Oracle database.
And it WORKS.

```
    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=" _
 + "(DESCRIPTION =" _
   + " (ADDRESS_LIST = " _
    + "  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [HostName])(PORT = [PortNumber])) " _
   + " ) " _
  + " (CONNECT_DATA = " _
  + "   (SERVICE_NAME = APPS)" _
 + "  ) " _
+ " );User Id=accountt;Password=my_pwd; "

    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "select cit2 from wild9 where zipl=72055"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    Label1.Text = dr.Item("cit2")
    conn.Dispose()
```

Im using Windows XP and the Oracle is on a remote window server.
However when I try to Add a data connection to the project: I get either:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.( If I leave the source as Local Database)

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ( If I change datasource to "jerry_apps"- which is what it is called in tnsnames.ora)

I copied the tnsnames.ora into the different directories to keep it the same.
I even configured an "Oracle Listner".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you connect to your database using a normal client (SQL+) ?

Comment: I can connect through Oracle SQL Developer Version 2.1.1.64.

Comment: <b>SOLVED</b> Not sure if I needed to, but I reinstalled Visual Studio 2010. Also reinstalled ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit.  Then I copied TNSNAMES.ORA and SQLNET.ORA over to C:\app\shall\product\11.2.0\client_3\Network\Admin.